# Unable to escape quote in dynamic SQL where file name hold quote in it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

```
declare @Path varchar(max) = 'E:\test\PS\Document\159203\Driver''s License and Insurance Card';

EXEC ('INSERT INTO table
        SELECT ''' + @id+ ''', BulkColumn FROM OpenRowSet ( Bulk ''' + @path + ''', Single_Blob) AS table')
```

Here path has file names which has quotes and I am unable to escape it and getting an error:

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 36
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ', Single_Clob) AS [NOTE_CONTENT]'

Comment: Path looks like E:\test\PS\Document\159203\Driver's License and Insurance Card

Comment: the path is not static it differs in all records that's why i made it comment

Answer (score 1):

You just need to escape the single quote again e.g.

```
declare @Path varchar(max) = 'E:\test\PS\Document\159203\Driver''s License and Insurance Card', @Id varchar(38) = '', @Sql varchar(max);

set @Sql = 'SELECT ''' + @id + ''', ''' + replace(@path,'''','''''') + '''';

print (@Sql);
exec (@Sql);
```

Note: Using SQL I can execute without access to the file, just adjust to suit.

Comment: if it is a single quote ?E:\test\PS\Document\159203\Driver's License and Insurance Card'

Comment: The example **IS** using a single quote... you always have to double single quotes, so even though there are 2 in the declare statement, there is only one in the string. Try it :)

Comment: how about to get dyanamically ?

Comment: @PranayKumar Try it!!!! :) its the same principle, its a generic solution, you always have to double up single quotes for use in SQL.

Comment: but i can escape it however i need to read the file using xp_fileexist and get out put using

Comment: @PranayKumar Then you need to update your question and ensure its a [MRE] - if you only ask half a question you'll only get half an answer.